# Replace values at a specific position in a list

Tags: python, list, replace

Maybe it's a quite a dumb question:

```
list = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1..., 1]
```

And now I want to replace the values from let's say `list[3:7][start:stop]` (excluding stop) with a 0.

```
list[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,..., 1]
```

If I try that, I'll get an error:

```
"TypeError: can only assign an iterable"
```

Do I need a `for` loop to get an iterator?

Solved my problem for list of lists:

```
list[column][position_line_xi:position_line_xj] = [z]*(position_line_xj - position_line_xi)
```

Comment: you can do it in place with lst[3:6] = [0]*4

Comment: FYI the length of the slice `[3:6]` is `3`. If you wanted `4` elements starting at index `3` the slice would be `[3:7]`

Comment: yes of course, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> my_list[3:6] = [0] * 3
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: That works fine. But now I#ve got a problem, that my list ist a list of lists: tilemap_1 = [[random.choice(resources) for w in range(screen_width)] for h in range(screen_height)]. So it doesnt change  a thing :( - Sry I'm quite new to programming.

Comment: What actually you are trying to change?

Comment: I've got a list of lists (Tilemap) with different numbers. Each number stands for a color. Now I want to change at a specific area of the list the value to another value (like in my question). But cause my list doesnt look like [a, ..., z] but [[a, ..., z]] the method mentioned does not affect anything. So after changing the value the lists looks exactly the same. I hope I expressed my self clearly enough (I'm not a native english speaker).

Comment: can i do this on list of lists `masked_content_list[0:count][index_of_columns_to_mask["Billing"]] = average`

Answer (score 2):

You can assign to a slice of a list.

```
>>> start = 3
>>> end = 6
>>> l[start:end] = [0]*(end-start)
>>> l
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```